# How to suppress Excel Services query warning in Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, excel-services

I am using Excel Services to display items from an Excel workbook that has a query connection for its data. Each time I load the Sharepoint page, the Excel Services web parts ask if I want to run the query. How do I suppress this warning? I found the 'Application Management' approach for on Prem farm, but there is no Application Management section in the Sharepoint Central Admin site for online. Is there another place to set the query warning to False?
"Be careful. This workbook contains one or more queries that might be unsafe. Do you want to enable these queries?"
[image: Query and Refresh Data warning]

Answer (score 0):

Because the option needs the SharePoint Central Admin level permission that is not opened to the public in Office 365 now. The feature to disable the ‘Data Refresh Warning’ is not available yet in SharePoint Online.

Reference:

http://itfreesupport.com/2014/12/sharepoint-error-external-data-refresh-failedwe-are-unable-to-refresh-one-or-more-data-connections-in-this-workbook-the-following-connections-failed-to-refresh/